# How to access "ApplicationWindow" reference in other QML file?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a file called *main.qml*, which instantiate *`ApplicationWindow`*.
I would like to  access this object(app) in other qml file.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:app
    title: "Title"
    visible: true
    property int keyboardPosition:10//need to access from other qml files for set/get
....
...
}
```

Is there any API available to access *qml* application object?
or
How to set application settings in qml. is it singleton class approach or any other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ApplicationWindow {
   id: app
   property ApplicationWindow appWindow : app
}
```

Then `appWindow` will be available to every object nested in the window in the object tree, because of dynamic scoping. So you can `appWindow.keyboardPosition` from anywhere. Note that if all you need to access is `keyboardPosition` - then you can do that from anywhere as well, as long as it is not overshadowed by another property with the same name up the object tree, you don't need to expose the window object as a property itself.

If you have multiple windows, the property will automatically resolve to the window the current object is in.

Comment: Now I can use application as scratchpad and can access the same from anywhere in qml..great answer...